# System crashes while using clearcase 8.0.1.x /9.0.1.x (checking out files) on windows 10 (1803) platform

Tags: windows-10, clearcase

After upgrading system to Windows 10 - os 1803 we are getting below issues while working with ClearCase 8.0.1.x/9.0.1.x

- Unable to checkin/checkout.
- Not able to create views.
- Not able to add any file to source control.

The system hangs & crashes while performing any ClearCase operation.
There is no error message, but I have attached screenshot for reference.

[image: error message]

Please let us know if there is any issue with the Windows 10 ver(1803), any security system enabled?
Or has ClearCase provided any fix?

We have tried 9.0.1.5 and issue still persists.

This is what we got from windows event log.

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  
The bugcheck was: 
   0x000000c2 (0x0000000000000004, 0x00000000535be990, 0x000000000004efd3, 0xfffff803e01848b1)
```

Comment: Maybe a permission issue: check your CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP and make sure your user is part of the primary group of a vob, or can wirite to the view storage folder. Where is your ClearCase view server? On which OS?

Comment: Hi ,

Thanks for your input.
   clearcase primary group is pointing to the right value and I am part of it.
    I am able to create snapshot view  but while creating dynamic view it hangs,   
it might be related to MVFS/W10.   

Clearcase view server is hosted on windows server 2008 R2 
and my machine has windows 10 ver 1803 OS

Comment: checked IBM document on limitations of clearcase with windows10..
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22002322
I have disabled the security provided on disks , still there seems to be something missing

Comment: That is typical of an incomplete installation of the ClearCase client (the MVFS part did not complete its installation): try and uninstall (as admin), reboot, re-install as admin

Comment: hello again,

uninstalled (cleaned the residue), rebooted and installed (all as admin) as suggested....
I can see mvfs tab in clearcase properties, I can see mvfs and cred manager service up and running. mfvs logs also do not show any error as well . I hope these checks are enough to know that mvfs has been installed properly ? unfortunately still facing the issue..

Any other suggestions/workaround on this are welcome . thank u for your time..

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact error message you are seeing? Also with what you can see in the ClearCase logs (views logs locally, or wiew_server.logs on the remote side): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm Also check the Windows event logs at the time of the view (failed) creation (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_intro_serverprocs_logs.htm)

Comment: this is what I got from windows event log. 

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x000000c2 (0x0000000000000004, 0x00000000535be990, 0x000000000004efd3, 0xfffff803e01848b1). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 53e8950e-b8fe-46e8-832d-5574b622107b

Comment: cleartool getlog -graphical -tag <view-name> pointed me to the clearcase view_server log, did not find any error there 

Using view D:\CCStore\views\<domain-name>\abc\abc_Win10_V1803_int.vws, on host: <server-name>


Edited the question with the error received (error is not very specific) , however it may not be of much help I suppose. ..

Comment: Do you have ClearCase doctor? and if yes, what is its output?

Comment: Make sure some of the Windows 10 features are not in conflict with ClearCase MVFS: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22002322

Comment: And check the Windows 10 support: https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=9637A890FEA011E49652B1059D0E4EB0&osPlatforms=Windows#! and https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/osTabViewDetails?dsrType=tsr&deliverableId=F6443B909D5411E7ABD1948A532C9330&osFamily=Windows&osId=1438971220672&product=Rational+ClearQuest+9.0.0.6&isDUOnly=undefined&osDisplay=Windows+10+Pro+x86-64&compIds=D007%7CD006%7CD005%7CD004%7CS002%7CS003%7CA001

Comment: clearcase doctor shows two error -> 1. NEED ADOBE ACROBAT READER....  2.DHCP client services are enabled.... Apart from that everything seems to be correct... 
and thanks for the link , I have pasted that link already , secure boot and device guard seems to have been disabled in the system...

Comment: Is this an issue for *all* Windows 10 users in your company or just yours?

Comment: sadly for most of them whoever has upgraded to windows 1803 ver :(
for people who are still using ver1709 it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

> for most of them whoever has upgraded to windows 1803 ver :( for people who are still using ver1709 it is working perfectly fine

Then I would recommand contacting IBM support: only them can update their [ClearCase 9/Windows 10 compatibility matrix](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=9637A890FEA011E49652B1059D0E4EB0&osPlatforms=Windows#) and confirm if MVFS is supported on a more recent (1803) Windows 10 edition.

Answer (score 0):

We also facing same problem and I have raised the case with IBM. Still not yet resolved. As IBM said there are some limitations to work ClearCase with windows 10 and windows 2016.

We tried all the options except Secure boot disable. If possible please do disable secure boot option in Windows 10 and try to checkin/checkout code from CleraCase

Note : It works for Snapshot views. That means the issue related to MVFS

Answer (score 0):

I'm seconding @VonC's recommendation to open a ticket with IBM. When you do that, save a step and collect a clearbug2 and a kernel memory dump to send in as soon as the case is opened. It will save the turn-around time of us asking you for it. If the installed programs list doesn't list installed security software (DLP, Privilege management sw like Avecto, other endpoint security tools), please list those separately as well.

I would also love to know who @ IBM told you there are "limitations" with Win10-1803.

There are a few issues with Windows 10 "version upgrades" breaking things, but they generally don't cause system crashes. Windows 10 upgrades are actually full OS installs that then (imperfectly) migrate application settings. Anything that uses custom network providers (ClearCase is one example) will find that the network providers will be broken or partially broken. Reinstalling is usually required. Again, that has not yet been reported as a **cause** of a BSOD.

If the upgrade/reinstall didn't fix view creation, please post a separate question on the view creation issue. There may be things we can do to the SMB 2 caches to allow view creation to work in cases where the view storage is not on the client host.

I noticed that the screen shot you posted is a Terminal Services disconnect screenshot. Does the issue only occur over a Terminal Services client connection or does it also happen on a local connection?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your input .

1. yes, we have opened up a ticket and provided the clearbug2 and kernel memory dump.

2.This document describes the liimitation ->http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22002322 ..  which was provided to us by the IBM support.

3.We have re-installed clearcase application many times , it seems to be installing properly!

4.It happens on both terminal and local connection.

Comment: looking into SMB2 caches by referring to this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff686200(v=ws.10)